# Почему не работает функция вывода шорткода wordpress do_shortcode()?

Tags: php, wordpress, видео, carousel, шорткод

На [сайте **wordpress**](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/26/) установлен плагин [WonderPlugin Carousel](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-carousel/) для отображения карусели с роликами ютуба во всплывающем окне.
Если добавлять шорткод в запись в стандартном редакторе `[wonderplugin_carousel id="1"]`, то все работает исправно так, как на [демо](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-carousel/).
А, если добавлять в темплейт страницы *php вставкой*

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[wonderplugin_carousel id="1"]'); ?>
```

то сама карусель не вращается и не всплывают видео с роликом, хотя подгружаются без проблем и структура `html` точно такая же - [демо](http://a-lot-of-money.ru/templates/26/)
Конфликтов в консоли нет, все плагины деактивированы, кроме самого самого плагина карусели. 
В чем может быть проблема и как ее можно устранить?

Comment: Всю карусель перекрывает .onepage-section:before . Код карусели рабочий

Comment: .wonderplugincarousel {
    z-index: 999;
}

Comment: @Рашен Беар хмм, точно, а для чего может использоваться `.onepage-section:before` ?

Comment: для вывода background, например. Там position: absolute; Можно этой секции поставить .onepage-section:before {
    z-index: 0;
}

Comment: @KAGG Design спасибо! напишите это как ответ - я отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно поставить в style.css

```
.wonderplugincarousel {
  z-index: 999;
}
```

или

```
.onepage-section:before {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Эта секция имеет position: absolute; и предназначена для вывода натягивания background. Она перекрывает карусель, из-за чего клики и ховеры до карусели не доходят.